# Не запускается простой код в эксплорере 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Подскажите пожалуйста. Попытался реализовать поле `комбинации`
Во всех браузерах запустился (firefox, opera, chrom, yandex) а в internet explorer не хочет. При этом консоль не выдает никаких ошибок. вот код:

```
index.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Проба перебора всех символов</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
    
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="combinations">
            <div id="combheader">
                <div id="combheadercaption">Комбинации</div>
            </div>
            <div id="combfield">
            <textarea id="textarea" rows="1" cols="12">Введите слово</textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="combnav">
                <button id="combgo">Получить</button>
                <button id="combclear">Очистить</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

app.js:

function permut8(arr, prepend) {   // функция для получения всех комбинаций букв слова
  var i, version, el, result = [];
  prepend = prepend || [];
  if(arr.length === 1) return [arr];
  for( i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if( arr.length === 2) {
      result.push( prepend.concat( [arr[i], arr[(i+1)%2]] ));
    } else {
      version = arr.slice();
      el = version.splice(i,1);
      result = result.concat( permut8( version, prepend.concat(el)));
    }
  }  
  return result;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#combgo').on('click', function () { 
    var znach = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
    if (znach.length >9) {
        document.getElementById('combfield').innerHTML = '<span>Количество комбинаций получится более трех миллионов!!! \
        Устройство может зависнуть. Попробуйте угадать слово на слух из проигрывателя.</span>'; 
    }
    else {
        var test = permut8( znach.split('') );
        let stroka = test.map( e=>e.join(' ')), newstroka='';
        for (let i = 0; i<stroka.length; i++) {
            newstroka = newstroka + stroka[i] + '<br>';
        }
        document.getElementById('combfield').innerHTML = newstroka;
        }
  });
  $('#combclear').on('click', function () { 
    document.getElementById('combfield').innerHTML = '<textarea id="textarea" rows="1" cols="12">Введите слово</textarea>';
    
    });
});
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужен ie10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
let stroka = test.map( e=>e.join(' ')), newstroka='';
...
```

У вас здесь использована стрелочная функция и директива `let`. В ie любых версий не работает первое (следует заменить на `function(e) {return e.join(' ')}`), второе же работает только в ie11 (здесь придется использовать `var`).

PS: и еще, могу посоветовать использовать весь функционал jq, в котором, например, вместо `document.getElementById` предусмотрен `$('#<some id>')`, а вместо `innerHTML` - `<some element>.html(<some html>)`. Ну, или не подключать jq вовсе...

Comment: ООО все отлично работает trenajor.me Спасибо огромное. Я программирую всего 2 месяца . На этом ресурсе для изучения языков всего лишь 40% кода моего, остальное взятое и переделанное из сети. Я боюсь, что моих знаний не хватит перейти на чистый js. Но за совет СПАСИБО!